# How can I wipe my android app content after user's subscription is over?

Tags: android

Is there a way to do it when the user's tablet is not connected with wifi? I don't want to rely on tablet's clock either as the user might change the tablet time to keep the content for longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Without connection to any network there is actually nothing user can't change on the device.
You may put a flag into preferences, indicating last subscription status and rely on that flag. Or you just can disable app functionality when network is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Each time user open your application while wifi is on, you check the right time from Internet and set a countdown . If countdown time finish , you wipe the data . This is the best idea I can find.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the AlarmManager.
Here is a link on how to do it:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Simply set an alarm with time depending the the user subscription time.
If you want to avoid the problem with the user changing the time on his phone you should simply listen about time change actions and re-create the alarm.

Those actions are :

```
Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK
Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
```

That way even if the user changed the time you can allway keep track of his subscription.